# Need to run code when React Native app closing

Tags: react-native

I tried using a useEffect hook in the App component like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('App mounted');

    return () => {
      console.log('App unmounted');
    };
  }, []);
```

However the console doesn't show the App unmounted message. Tested on an Android device with a blank app. The way I closed the app was by pressing ||| on the tablet and then Close All.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend you to use `AppState`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      AppState.removeEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);
    };
 }, []);

const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
    console.log('the app is closed');
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! But I get the impression from the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate#app-states) that this state is only supported on iOS. Also, the app apparently becomes "inactive" when entering the multitasking view. So, for my app at least, it seems "background" is the better option.

Comment: But the background is coming when app is in minimized too. Did you get any other solution for this? I am looking for Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

removeEventListener() is now deprecated you should use remove() instead

You can check this doc in detail.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.67/appstate#removeeventlistener

```
useEffect(() => {
    const appStateId = AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

    return () => {
      appStateId.remove(console.log('the app is closed'));
    };
 }, []);

const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
    console.log('the app is closed');
  }    
}
```